# I have a problem in unity with my c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void Update ()
{
    if(CollectionSystem.theScore > 9)
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce (0, jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange); 
            CollectionSystem.theScore -= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi i'm new in unity and programming in general and i wanted to make my own first game, but i have a little problem.
So i'm trying to make a game where you can collect coins and when you have 10 you can jump.
When the player jumped he looses 10 coins. Can somebody help me?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to jump **every frame** while the key is pressed?

I guess you rather want to use [`GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)  which is only true in the one frame the button was pressed down.

```
private const int PRICE_JUMP = 10;

private void Update ()
{
    // Why 9? Wouldn't you rather want to chekc if you have enough points to perform the jump?
    if(CollectionSystem.theScore >= PRICE_JUMP)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce (0, jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange); 
            CollectionSystem.theScore -= PRICE_JUMP;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first, in the update function you can make an if statement that checks if the player has enough coins, like this:

```
if (CollectionSystem.theScore >= 10)
{
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
         {
             rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
             CollectionSystem.theScore -= 10;
         }
}
```

I recommend you making the amount you want to subtract public, so you can modify it in the inspector. Another thing that I recommend doing is making a price for each time you jump because then you can modify it in the inspector and make life easier for you.

Notice how I used `GetKeyDown` instead of `GetKey`? That is because if the player holds down space, he can jump forever with having 0 coins, and when he lets go, only then he can't jump anymore. You can easily fix this by using `GetKeyDown` instead. That makes it so that even if you hold down space, unity will only make the player jump on the first frame and that's it. Another thing to note is that if you see that the player when moving having jittery/stuttering, that's because you are using physics and instead of `Update`, you have to use `FixedUpdate`.

I hope this helped a bit! :D